# How do I set the default kernel parameters in CentOS for all existing and future kernels?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, grub, linux-kernel

I'd like to remove the `rhgb` and `quiet` kernel parameters which are used by default when the kernel is booted in CentOS 6, but I want this to apply to all currently installed kernels as well as any kernels installed in the future. I need to do this from a script, so manually editing files isn't an option and any file changes should be done as cleanly as possible.

In Debian/Ubuntu I would change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and then run `update-grub`. I can't find such a setting in `/etc/sysconfig/grub` or `/etc/sysconfig/kernel` however, nor is there an `update-grub` script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Debian/Ubuntu, `grub.cfg` is fully generated by scripts and any manual changes made to it will be clobbered. In RHEL/CentOS however, `grub.cfg` is modified by scripts but manual changes are persisted, and is actually the canonical location for certain settings.

The tool which manages `grub.cfg` is [`grubby`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/grubby), which is called by `/sbin/new-kernel-pkg` when kernels are installed or removed. The `--copy-default` parameter is passed to `grubby` when a new kernel is installed, which causes it to copy the kernel parameters from the current default kernel. Setting the default kernel parameters for future-installed kernels is therefore done by editing the entry for the default kernel in `grub.cfg`.

If you weren't automating this you could simply edit `grub.cfg` manually and change all the current kernel entries. However, you can use `grubby` to modify `grub.cfg` in order to avoid parsing it or writing regular expressions. For example, this will remove the `rhgb` and `quiet` parameters from the specified kernel version.

```
# grubby --update-kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64 --remove-args="rhgb quiet"
```

There doesn't seem to be an option to list the currently configured kernels however, so you'll have to discover these another way. One option is to just look for `vmlinuz` files in `/boot/`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
for KERNEL in /boot/vmlinuz-*; do
    grubby --update-kernel="$KERNEL" --remove-args="rhgb quiet"
done
```

Comment: You can have it apply to all current and any future kernels by using `ALL`.  
`grubby --update-kernel=ALL --remove-args="rhgb quiet"`

Comment: In case someone else is having troubles deciphering this, what it's saying is that any changes you make to the kernel parameters in ``grub.conf`` will automatically be added to any kernel updates

Answer (score 1):

We found a solution for CentOS! yum uses grubby itself! (strace, thank you!)
grubby has the option "--copy-default" and I think yum runs grubby with it.
So only thing you should do is to add in grub.conf all kernel options you need to current default kernel and reboot. After reboot you can install new kernel!